# flickity: how to use contain: true with wraparound

Tags: javascript, flickity

I have an image carousel, I want the carousel start with the first image aligned to the left using `contain:true` but at the same time I want to be able to use `wrapAround:true` so that it creates a loop.

On the document it says `contain:true` doesn't work with `wrapAround:true` but is there a way to work around it?

My current flickity CSS looks like this:

```
$('.carousel').flickity({
  // options
  lazyLoad: 2,
  contain: true,
});
```

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-image"></div>
  <div class="carousel-image"></div>
</div>
```

[image]